# Maven´s equivalent to AntCall

Tags: maven

I have a POM file where I call wsimport for several files using similar configurations:

```
<project>

    <build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <executions>

                <execution>
                    <id>client.controlevagas</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>${wsdl.package.basic}.client.controlevagas</packageName>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>${wsdl.dir}/ControleVagasWebService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlLocation>/${wsdl.base}/ControleVagasWebService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                    </configuration>
                </execution> 

                <execution>
                    <id>client.downloadservice</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packageName>${wsdl.package.basic}.client.downloadservice</packageName>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>/${wsdl.dir}/DownloadService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlLocation>/${wsdl.base}/DownloadService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>

    </build>

</project>
```

The execution is called more than 20 times. Obviously it becomes repeated. So is there a way to make it better? May be using something similar to [AntCall](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html)? Or some kind of macro

Comment: Why is it called more than 20 times? Do you have so much executions?

Comment: Because I must execute for 20 different WSDL files, each one with their specific package.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the way depending on your architecture having 20 different modules which contain the generation from the 20 different wsdl files cause their intentions is different ( I assume so). Separation of Concerns.

Furthermore the [iterator-maven-plugin](http://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/) might be worth a look. I'm not sure if it will solve your problem.

Apart from that i would take a look [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/)